# NASM on DOS (Intel 8086): invalid effective address

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm, x86-16, bochs

I am writing code for DOS using Bochs. I am compiling the program using **NASM**
Lets suppose i have the following code:

```
[BITS 16]

    SEGMENT code

..start:
mov ax, data
mov ds, ax
mov bx, msg
mov al, byte [bx]
int 21h

    SEGMENT data

msg  DB "teststring", 00h
```

Why is it that nasm complains on the line:

```
mov al, byte [bx]
```

of **invalid effective address**?

If instead of using **bx** i use the **si** registry, the program compiles an works as supposed, loading the ascii value of **t** in **al**.

Why is it?

EDIT: Found that I can't use BX for indexing.
If I wanted to load what's pointed in a determined part of the data segment, you could do the following:

```
mov ax, data
mov ds, ax
mov si, msg
mov al, byte [si] ; Loading first char
inc si
mov al, byte [si] ; Loading second char
```

If I wanted to keep **si** pointing to the start of the string, i could then use BX to be the offset:

```
mov al, byte [si + bx]
```

or even

```
mov al, byte [si + n] ; where n is an integer value
```

But to my understanding, bx could also be used, so the problem still resides.

Comment: Try mov al, [bx] or mov al, ds:[bx] - I'm pretty sure it's a valid addressing mode...  You point dx to your message and then use bx, is that a typo?

Answer (score 3):

I think you made more than one typo in your question :-) First of, in 16 bit mode [bp][bx][si][di] are all valid addressing modes. Even the old 8086 can use [bx] as an effective address.
Where as [dx] can not be used in 16 bit mode, afaik it needs to be running in 32 bit mode. Together with your line

```
mov dx, msg
```

preceding

```
mov al, byte [bx]
```

I assume you wrote in fact 'mov al, [dx]' and nasm is correctly complaining about [dx] as an invalid address. So if you meant, you found out you can't use [bx], you were wrong - you found out that you need to take more care in not misspelling "b" for "d".

Comment: That should teach me to check my examples better next time :D. I wrote bx in the code, and it does complain about invalid effective address.

Comment: I used nasm to assemble the file you gave - the line in question 'mov al, byte [bx]' just assembles fine.

Answer (score 1):

You sure the error is not on this line?

```
mov ds, data
```

Perhaps you meant:

```
mov ds, ax
```

Comment: oh, my bad, yes, i meant mov ds, ax (Copied incorrectly the code :P)